# Are there any resources that explain what each of the Flutter TextTheme values affect?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter has a class named TextTheme which can be used to set the styling of text across your entire app. It has several different fields which decide which style will be used on which Text widgets. The names hint at what they are for but some are also quite vague. I have not been able to find any documentation that explains exactly which widgets these styles will end up automatically getting applied to.

For example `title` will change the title text in an AppBar, which seems obvious enough... but how about `body2` or `display3`?

Are there any resources that explain each of these and which widgets they will apply to (ideally visually)?

```
class TextTheme extends Diagnosticable {
  const TextTheme({
    this.display4,
    this.display3,
    this.display2,
    this.display1,
    this.headline,
    this.title,
    this.subhead,
    this.body2,
    this.body1,
    this.caption,
    this.button,
    this.subtitle,
    this.overline,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the document about TextTheme is [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html).

I don't think these styles will automatically apply to, it's just an option for you apply to text.

Comment: I am familiar with that page. It shows that each item is styled as by default, but what I am looking for is documentation about which widget each of these styles automatically apply to.

Comment: I don't think these styles will automatically apply to, it's just an option for you apply to text.

Comment: Thanks @hoangquyy, I suspected that may be the case, but I could have sworn title style was automatically applying to my AppBar, I may have just been confused. If you edit your answer to include your last comment, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelPeterson if you add the document about TextTheme first in the post, maybe i don't answer it so I think you should add everything you have found. It will not make someone misunderstand to down vote you or down vote the one who answer.